# AsyncTask comparar 2 jsons

Tags: android, asynctask

Estou tentando fazer com que ao popular o meu list view com um json, ele confira as informações de outro json e me retorne um link no qual usarei para preencher fotos porem tudo ocorre certo consigo `setar` o link em uma class mas na hora de recebê-lo sempre recebo `null`

`GET.class` <- classe aonde recebo o 1º json para popular

```
class GET extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Activity activity;
    String nome;
    String nome2;
    String idpaciente;
    String idmedico;

    ListView lv;
    public GET(Activity activity, ListView lv, String nome) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lv = lv;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resposta = null;
        try {
            if(Utils.verifyConnection(activity)) {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resposta = buffer.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }

    @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        JSONArray array = null;
        try {
            if(Utils.verifyConnection(activity)) {
                array = new JSONArray(s);
                int i = 0;
                List<Consulta> consultas = new ArrayList<>();
                String dados = "";
                while (i < array.length()) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = obj.getInt("id");
                    String medico = obj.getString("medico");
                    String paciente = obj.getString("paciente");
                    int status = obj.getInt("status");
                    String rece = obj.getString("receita");
                    String horario = obj.getString("horario");
                    idmedico = obj.getString("idmedico");
                    idpaciente = obj.getString("idpaciente");
                    String espec = obj.getString("especialidade");
                    String remedios = obj.getString("remediosMinistrados");
                    String observacoes = obj.getString("observacoes");
                    String tratamento = obj.getString("tratamento");
                    String imagem = obj.getString("imagem");
                    String linkreceita = obj.getString("linkReceita");

                    new PHOTO(activity, lv, nome).execute("http://infasstec.com.br/desenvolvimento/android/foto.json");
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "id"+nome +"idpaci"+ idpaciente +"idmed" + idmedico, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, id+ medico+ idmedico+paciente+idpaciente, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (nome.equals(idmedico)) {
                        if (status == 1) {
                            String teste = idpaciente;
                            guardaFoto guarda = new guardaFoto();

                                new fotolist(activity, lv, teste).execute("http://infasstec.com.br/desenvolvimento/android/foto.json"); <- chamo a outra class para receber o link da foto

                                Consulta consulta = new Consulta();

                                consulta.setId(id);
                                consulta.setMed(medico);
                                consulta.setPaci(paciente);
                                consulta.setAbertas(status);
                                consulta.setRec(rece);
                                consulta.setHorario(data_certa(horario));
                                consulta.setEspe(espec);
                                consulta.setReme(remedios);
                                consulta.setDesc(observacoes);
                                consulta.setTrat(tratamento);
                                consulta.setImagem(imagem);
                                consulta.setLink(linkreceita);


                                //consulta.setFoto(guarda.getPicture());


                                consulta.setNome("Paci. " + paciente);
                                String a = guarda.getPicture();
                                //Toast.makeText(activity, i +a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                consultas.add(consulta);



                        } else {

                        }
                    } else if (nome.equals(idpaciente)) {
                        if (status == 1) {
                            String teste = idmedico;
                            new fotolist(activity, lv, teste).execute("http://infasstec.com.br/desenvolvimento/android/foto.json"); <- chamo a outra class para receber o link da foto
                            guardaFoto guarda = new guardaFoto();
                            Consulta consulta = new Consulta();

                            consulta.setId(id);
                            consulta.setMed(medico);
                            consulta.setPaci(paciente);
                            consulta.setAbertas(status);
                            consulta.setRec(rece);
                            consulta.setHorario(data_certa(horario));
                            consulta.setEspe(espec);
                            consulta.setReme(remedios);
                            consulta.setDesc(observacoes);
                            consulta.setTrat(tratamento);
                            consulta.setImagem(imagem);
                            consulta.setLink(linkreceita);
                            consulta.setFoto(guarda.getPicture()); <- Pego o link que foi setado no getPicture()


                            consulta.setNome("Dr. " + medico);

                            //Toast.makeText(activity, consulta.getFoto(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            consultas.add(consulta);

                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                    i++;

                }

                lv.setAdapter(new ConsultasAdapter(activity, consultas));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String data_certa(String text)
    {
        String res = "";
        try
        {
            String partes[] = text.split(" ");
            String partes_partes[] = partes[0].split("-");
            res += partes_partes[2] + "-" + partes_partes[1] + "-" + partes_partes[0] + " " + partes[1];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            res = text;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

`fotolist.class` <- Classe aonde pego o 2 json para comparar e setar os links

```
class fotolist extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Activity activity;
    String nome;
    String nome2;
    String idpaciente;
    String idmedico;
    static String link;

    ListView lv;
    public fotolist(Activity activity, ListView lv, String teste) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lv = lv;
        this.nome = teste;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resposta = null;
        try {
            if(Utils.verifyConnection(activity)) {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resposta = buffer.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        JSONArray array = null;
        try {

            if(Utils.verifyConnection(activity)) {
                array = new JSONArray(s);
                int i = 0;
                List<Consulta> consultas = new ArrayList<>();
                String dados = "";
                while (i < array.length()) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = obj.getString("id");
                    //String nome1 = obj.getString("nome");
                    String foto = obj.getString("foto");

                    if (nome.equals(id)) {
                        guardaFoto guarda = new guardaFoto();
                        guarda.setPicture(foto); <- seto o link para receber com o getPicture()
                        link = guarda.getPicture();
                        //Toast.makeText(activity, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    i++;

                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

`guardaFoto.class` <- classe aonde armazeno e pego os links

```
public class guardaFoto {
    String foto;

    public void setPicture(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }
    public String getPicture() { return foto; }


}
```

Utilizando breakpoints consigo ver que a `guardaFoto.class` recebeu o link mas ao tentar receber sempre retorna null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce cria a Task

```
 new fotolist(activity, lv, teste).execute("http://infasstec.com.br/desenvolvimento/android/foto.json");
```

Mas não está usando o resultado que está dentro dela.

Guarde a instancia

```
fotos =  new fotolist(activity, lv, teste).execute("http://infasstec.com.br/desenvolvimento/android/foto.json");
```

E depois numa ação de um botão por exemplo você pode pegar o link com 
    fotos.link

Outra coisa, você está setando o link dentro de um for, você só vai ter o ultimo dado quando for utiliza-lo, talvez você queira usar uma List invés de String

PS: Use [CamelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) em nome de classes.

Comment: A parte do `while` que seta o link no `setPictute()` ele irá comprara o id e sempre será um link que irei receber então não seria o caso de usar um list.

Comment: Porém eu teria de receber este link pelo `getPicture()` e tudo está sendo feito no onCreate pois são imagens de usuários que ficariam ao lado de suas consultas médicas

Comment: Bem, você tem duas soluções, por um listener e informar quando pega um novo (ou arrumar seu onPostExecute), ou então voce passa a ImageView para sua Task e já seta a imagem depois de baixar que é mais facil.